# How to fetch new records by using limit in php mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, web, blogs

I am making an infinite scroll app in which records from database will be fetch. When the user clicks "Load More" button a function is called for retrieving data from database.

My problem is that when I am running this(below) query every Time I am getting the same records.

```
SELECT ArticleTitle, PreviewText, PreviewImage FROM Articles ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 4
```

regards....

Comment: Using the LIMIT and OFFSET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You need to set a offset in hidden field.
- On clicking `load more`, you need to get offset, calculate next batch and update offset in same hidden field
- that new offset, should be passed to query.

your query looks like

```
SELECT ArticleTitle, PreviewText, PreviewImage 
FROM Articles 
ORDER BY ID DESC 
LIMIT 0, 4
```

first time offset is 0

next time it will be 5 (if you are loading 5 records every time)

then next time it will be 10 and so on

Comment: can you please show me how to dynamically change the value of offset without this pagination thing...thanks

Comment: You can make an input field hidden and value is 5. show first 5 rows. 
a button clicked, get value of that hidden field and add 5 more, 
1st iteration: 5 in field, so that 5 will be offset, new value of field will be 10 
2nd iteration: 10 in field, so that 10 will be offset, new value of field will be 15
and so on

Comment: $offset = 0; can I use if(isset($_POST['Offset_Field_Request'])){
    $offset = $offset + 4;
}

Comment: Yup seems ok for this scenario

Comment: But as soon as I am sending new Ajax request  the value of $offset and $Limit is same. ie; the variables are having same value and same records are being fetched.

Comment: that offset you need to add in ajax request. 
Like get current offset from hidden field and add 4 and pass to the request. also update new offset to hidden field.

Answer (score 1):

You've to use the OFFSET and LIMIT together like this.

**Explanation:** The **OFFSET** value is also most often used together with the **LIMIT** keyword. The OFF SET value allows us to specify **which** row to start from retrieving data. By the way you can also omit the OFFSET keyword and use like this `LIMIT 0,4` which tells to get 4 rows starting from 0. [see more](https://www.guru99.com/limit.html)

```
SELECT ArticleTitle, PreviewText, PreviewImage 
FROM Articles 
ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 4 OFFSET 0 

SELECT ArticleTitle, PreviewText, PreviewImage 
FROM Articles 
ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 4 OFFSET 5
```

Comment: Just a note: the OP has to remind that the client side must keep track one what or another the previous offset and send the information to the server script, or else it won't change much the problem